# Python: Return the values of a list for each match

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python 3 and have trouble returning values from 2 lists for each match.

```
locations = [("ngv", 4, 0), ("town hall", 4, 4),("myhotel",  2, 2), ("parliament", 8, 5.5), ("fed square",  4, 2)]

tour = ["ngv", "fed square", "myhotel"]
```

My code finds the matches but won't return the location coordinates as well.

```
['ngv', 'fed square', 'myhotel']
```

My current code is:

```
places = [u[0] for u in locations]
new = [i for i in tour if i in places]
print(new)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the intermediate list comprehension, simply:

```
new = [i for i in locations if i[0] in tour]
```

Note if `locations` and `tour` contain many items then you can speed up your code and reduce time complexity by making `tour` a `set` first, such as `tour = set(tour)`

Comment: Nice and concise.

Comment: thanks!! i managed to get it into a dictionary format with {places: locationcoordinatestuples} - if i were to do the same function as above how would i do it???